# removing 0 values in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have tried both these methods to remove the 0 values from this array but to no avail

```
foreach ($matches as $array_key=>$array_item)
{
  if($matches[$array_key] == 0)
  {
    unset($matches[$array_key]);
  }
}

var_dump ($matches[$array_key]);
```

and this

```
$matches_without_nulls = array_filter($matches);
print_r($matches_without_nulls[1]);
```

However, the string I keep getting is this

```
{ [0] => string(7) "2337667" [1] => string(7) "2335765" [2] => string(7) "2332651" [3] => string(7) "2328582" [4] => string(1) "0" [5] => string(1) "0" [6] => string(1) "0" [7] => string(1) "0" }
```

Any idea on what is happening?

Comment: in `print_r($matches_without_nulls[1]);` why the `[1]`. Seems to me, you're not accessing your data correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your array does not contains `0` (integer), it contains `"0"` (string):

```
if($matches[$array_key] == "0")
```

That will do the trick.

PS: Why are you printing out a none-existing value `$matches[$array_key]`? It has been unset, so `NULL` is provided. Test your code with `var_dump ($matches);`.

---

I just tried this and it works just fine:

```
$matches = array (
        "2337667",
        "2335765",
        "2332651",
        "2328582",
        "0",
        "0",
        "0",
        "0"
    );

foreach ( $matches as $array_key => $array_item ) {
    if( $matches[$array_key] == "0") {
        unset($matches[$array_key]);
    }
}

var_dump ($matches);

//output

array(4) {
    [0]=> string(7) "2337667"
    [1]=> string(7) "2335765"
    [2]=> string(7) "2332651"
    [3]=> string(7) "2328582"
}
```

Comment: [`var_dump("0" == 0) // true`](http://codepad.viper-7.com/ZlVond) I don't think this is the problem here.

Answer (score 3):

Try changing:

```
if($matches[$array_key] == 0)
```

to

```
if($matches[$array_key] == "0")
```

Answer (score 3):

Your original code was actually [removing all the `0` entries along with other strings](http://codepad.org/NjGHbuu5). You better use [array_filter](http://php.net/array_filter) function for this.

```
array_filter($matches, function($e){return $e!=0;});
```

Only array_filter [**without callback also works**](http://codepad.org/uWHElNbX). I dont know why it didn't worked for you.

Comment: You can use array_filter without a callback, and "all entries of input equal to FALSE (see converting to boolean) will be removed." Which "0" will equal to FALSE

Comment: Yeah, I know this. But see OP has tried without parameters and didn't succeed.

Answer (score 2):

you can use **array_filter()** function. Click the below url

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Answer (score 0):

Compare the values instead of using keys

```
foreach($matches as $array_key=>$array_item)
{
     if( $array_item == 0 ) // if($matches[$array_key] == 0)
     {
          unset($matches[$array_key]);
     }
}
var_dump ($matches);
```

OR

You can also try something like below

```
foreach($matches as $array_key=>$array_item)
{
     if( !$array_item ) // if $array_item is below, it will get in the loop and excute your code.
     {
          unset($matches[$array_key]);
     }
}
var_dump ($matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

hi guys i credited Dainis Abols because he helped me solve the problem

the issue was multiple index; here is the working solution

```
foreach($matches[1] as $array_key=>$array_item)
{
  if($matches[1][$array_key] == "0")
  {
    unset($matches[1][$array_key]);
  }
} 
var_dump ($matches[1])
```

;